# Best Way To Magento 2 Installation

Tags: magento2, installation, migration

I am planning to migrate the Magento from 1 to 2. so, I like to install the Magento2 first, then the Magento 2 installation I found the following procedures

```
1) Using composer
2) Git clone.
3) Using Web Setup Wizard
```

May I know which one is the best way to install the Magento2 and why?

Thanks in advance for your ideas and support

Comment: Best way to Composer you can follow below link : [https://www.goivvy.com/blog/magento-2-upgrade](https://www.goivvy.com/blog/magento-2-upgrade)

Comment: You should go with composer.

Answer (score 1):

You have missed another option called **Web setup wizard**.

You can download latest version of Magento 2 from magento open source section from magento.com without sample data.

Open source download page link https://magento.com/tech-resources/download

First option `Full Release (ZIP with no Sample Data)` is very suitable for migration as its not have any initial data.

Upload it to your server exract it in web root of your server generally `public_html` or `www` folder.

After extracting magento application zip in your webroot open url assigned to web root in simple your website url.

A web setup wizard is guide to install Magento 2.

Steps should be like that.

**Step 1: Readiness Check**

This step decides your system is available to install Magento 2 or not.

**Step 2: Add your database**

You have to enter all the database information here.

**Step 3: Web Configuration**

This step you have to set up some Web configuration.

**Your Store Address:** Full URL of your Magento 2 store

**Magento Admin Address:** Backend url handle

Expand Advanced Options and enter the following fields:

**HTTPS Options:** Mark the checkbox to Use HTTPS for Magento Storefront or Use HTTPS for Magento Admin

**Apache Rewrites:** Mark the checkbox to enable your server

**Encryption Key:** You can use a Magento generated key or your own encryption key.

**Step 4:** Customize Your Store

After your web was configured, your store is the next step.

Set the information below:

**Sample Data** Mark the Use Sample Data checkbox if you want to use demo data.

**Store Default Time Zone:** your time zone locate

**Store Default Currency:** the currency you accept for payment.

**Store Default Language:** your primary language.

**Expand Advanced Modules Configuration:** (you can set it on your own or let it as default)

Select the checkbox of each module you want to install or mark select all checkbox to install the module you need.

That is step 4, tap next to go to step 5.

**Step 5: Create Admin Account**

Before you start Magento 2 installation process, you need to create your own admin account.

Enter the following fields:

**New Username**

**New E-Mail**

**New Password**

**Confirm Password**

Check the information again for sure. Then Next.

**Step 6: Install: Final step of Magento 2 installation wizard**

Click on **Install Now** and wait until the process is done.